# Does having a single sprite sheet instead of multiple images improve performance in opengl rendering in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, sprite

i was wondering there are 20 independent images is there any performance improvement if we just use one sprite that has all these images does that improve performance or it doesnt change much? BTW i'm trying to render with opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will usually improve performance provided that the net effect is that you change the active texture much more infrequently.

That's because the GPU caches textures between main storage and drawing. If you change textures then that cache will be flushed. If you continue using the same texture then it's likely the cache will work effectively, saving trips out to the much slower main storage.

On phones it's normal to have the physical RAM be shared by the CPU and the GPU, so accessing that is costly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, as it depends on lots of factors, but generally - yes, having combined resources usually leads to performance benefits. The main is reason is that you don't perform texture switches while drawing the frame, which means you don't have to change hardware state, upload the data multiple times and so on.

However, there some possible downsides: you might screw up in case you want texture wrapping to occur, bad packing of sprites might increase your texture size and so on.

To sum up: go for it, but wisely :)