# Android openGL how to cut off sprite sheets efficiently?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new in OpenGL world and I have question about performance and technique:

i have read [followed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301021/does-having-a-single-sprite-sheet-instead-of-multiple-images-improve-performance) about performance,

seems like yo use the same texture multiple times leads to better performance.

Got it.

**How can I do that in openGL?**

**[option 1]**

use  Sprite sheet let's say 3x3 like:

[image]

in this case i need cut off or shift it and show one after one, in `canvas.drawBitmap` i can use `Rect`

```
public void update() {  
    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % 3;
}

...

int srcX = currentFrame * width;

Rect  src = new Rect(srcX, 0, srcX+width, height);
Rect  dst = new Rect(x, y, x+width, y+height);
canvas.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, null);
..
```

**[option 2]**

Use 9 images and add all of them like:

```
for(int loop = 0; loop < 9; loop++){

  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[loop]);
   ....
}
```

2nd option works but I need 1st one.

Please help,

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by updating the vertices' texture coordinates, which effectively specify the region of the spritesheet you're drawing. The answer I gave to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670066/what-is-a-technique-to-animate-objects-from-sprite-sheet-in-opengl-android) basically covers it already.